# How does a double pointer reconcile with a shared_ptr?

Tags: c++, pointers, shared-ptr, abi

Upfront disclosure: I think the entire thing is nonsense and "works" by chance, but I found this code and it seems to "work" for low-enough values of work (as in it does not crash when run, which doesn't mean much), and I don't get why.

The issue at hand is an `extern "C"` API exposed as a DLL/so, which is then called over FFI (by Python in this case), but the `extern "C"` code uses `shared_ptr`. And yet it moves.

The C++ code:

```cpp
#include <memory>
 
extern "C" {
  int make(std::shared_ptr<int> p) {
    p = std::make_shared<int>(42);
    return 0;
  }
 
  int get(std::shared_ptr<int> p) {
    return *p;
  }
}
```

the caller:

```py
import ctypes
 
lib = ctypes.CDLL('lib.so')
 
p = ctypes.c_void_p()
lib.make(ctypes.byref(p))
print(lib.get(ctypes.byref(p)))
```

After building the C++ code as a shared library (named `lib.so`), the Python code runs fine and does print `42`. This code was tested on macOS/ARM64 compiled with Clang but the original code this was munged from reportedly works on Linux/ARM32 (compiled with GCC) and Windows/AMD64 (compiled with msvc).

My working hypothesis is that in all these runtimes `shared_ptr` happens to have the object pointer as first members, and the compilers decide to pass it by reference in order to avoid the copy (and thus incref/decref), thus `make` writes the object pointer over Python's `p`, and writes the control block into space (maybe somewhere on the stack). When the shared pointer is freed the memory remains accessible (possibly because it's in a small object pool / page rather than being unmapped).

Then `get` does not need to touch the refcount (because gain passed by ref) so it just double-derefs our pointer, which is an UAF but the memory is still around and it works out.

Note: in the original there is no UAF because the shared_ptr is obtained from a longer-lived structure, so this simplified version is a touch worse than the original.

Comment: `make` is passing by *value*. Doesn't it need to at least pass by reference/pointer?

Comment: Your code is **not** working. It is **broken**. That is, it is not doing the thing that a C++ programmer would expect it to do by looking at the C++ part of the code. Python **breaks into** your C++ code and does illegal stuff. It is impossible to transfer 42 from `make` to `get` using correct C++ calls.

Comment: @n.m. Note that there's nothing wrong with asking why apparently-nonsense code doesn't crash due to weird ABI stuff, but mostly as a curiosity. Nobody should run this code and expect it to actually work even though it somehow does work

Comment: @user253751 "Doesn't crash" and "work" are two different things.

Comment: @MooingDuck that us the biggest question I have, see my working hypothesis as to how it could be working. I would expect that a reference or pointer be required but this work as is on Clang 14 and 15, and gcc, and apparently msvc (this actual code was not checked but my colleague compiler and ran what this was simplified from).

Comment: Some possible leads: shared_ptr is probably 16 bytes (on 64-bit architectures) while void* is 8 bytes. Sometimes memory allocators allocate extra memory e.g. it may round up to nearest 16 bytes. In some ABIs, all objects are passed as references and the caller has to make the copy if it doesn't want that.

Comment: @n.m. this goes beyond not crashing, the values transfer fine and the code this was simplified from has been running for years with no noticeable issues. It terrifies me, and the entire reason I posted it is that I do not understand, my knowledge of calling conventions, C++ abi, and assembly, are not sufficient to actually figure out what `make` is up to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some speculative facts:

- A shared_ptr is often 16 bytes (on 64-bit architectures) while void* is 8 bytes. A shared_ptr contains a pointer to the object it refers to, then another pointer to a "control block" containing the refcount and destructor. (This is just one possible implementation of shared_ptr)
- Overwriting memory doesn't have to immediately lead to a crash; often the memory allocator even allocates more memory than you ask for (e.g. it may round up to a multiple of 16 bytes)
- Non-trivial class types are passed by reference. Yes, really. Just like you wrote `&` after the type. I'm not making this up. See for example the [Itanium ABI](https://refspecs.linuxbase.org/cxxabi-1.83.html#normal-call) on which a lot of ABIs are based. In order to simulate the parameter *not* being a reference, the *caller* makes a copy and then destroys it after the call. You didn't.

So, probably: You were meant to pass a reference to a `shared_ptr` to the `make` function. You did. The `make` function overwrote it with a real bona-fide `shared_ptr`. Then, instead of destroying the object like you were supposed to by the ABI (and thereby making it pretend to not be a reference), you passed the same reference to the `get` function which read the new value assigned inside `make`.

Comment: "Non-trivial class types are passed by reference. [...] See for example the Itanium ABI" that is probably the bit of knowledge I was most missing. I assumed it *might* be an optimisation the compilers perform, but seeing that it's the defined Itanium ABI, and it matches the assembly for `get` (which is simple enough to read) pretty much confirms it. I was looking around copy elision optimisation but it didn't seem like function parameter is a normal copy elision case so that came up empty.